# Handling exception in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exception

I found a line of code throwing exception, sometimes, I tried to surround it with catch block, but swift compiler says there is nothing that throws excepions! please check attachment.

NOTE : I am using HTMLKit

[image: XCode warning]

Comment: Try/catch in Swift can only be used where and function is explicitly defined to `throw`.  You cannot catch runtime exceptions, such as unexpected `nil` and so on. What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Please create http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.And instead of posting image of code post actual code using the editor.

Comment: @Paulw11It's NSRangeException or something like that!

Comment: @Neel I attached screenshot to show warning, but you are right :)